# ReactJS web app: Selective Mobile Scrolling Bug

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll

I am working an ReactJS web app. We primarily style it with styled-components, and sometimes uses index.css for global styles (body, html, etc)

The app has an app header, a page header and a container of additional components.

I am experiencing a weird bug where the certain mobile devices cannot scroll down. Specifically the Sony Xperia XCompact and the Samsung S8.

The .js files :
(The components are spread in multiple files, I tried my best to grab everything that might be related.)

```
// app.js
const AppHeader = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  height: 100px;
`;

const PageHeaderContainer = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
    max-width: 414px;
    height: 100%;
`

export default = () => ( 
<AppHeader/>
<PageHeaderContainer>
    <Greeting/>
    <PageTitle/>
</PageHeaderContainer>
<IntroductionSlider>
    <Container>
        {/*more components*/}
    </Container>
</IntroductionSlider>
)
```

The index.css:

```
html, body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This code works **fine** in the latest version of Chrome, in Opera, in several mobile browsers ( Pixel 2, S10, Pixel 3, IPhone 7).

But scrolling somehow would be disabled in Sony Xperia XCompact and Samsung S8+.

I currently have a temporary fix, where if I change height of `body` to auto instead of 100%, the scrolling would be enabled again (tested on the Sony phone). But I am having trouble to understand why is this happening.

A lot of this code is inherited; I'm fairly new to the job and still trying to understand what's going on / how things work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Mobile Chrome that was updated a while ago.
Try this or wait for a new update.

```
width:calc(100% - 1px);
```